# Lambda Layer for Normalization in Keras

Tags: keras, normalization

i was trying to normalize my input and output data through the scikit-learn object MinMaxScaler. I have some questions about this process:

1 - How can i use the MinMaxScale inside a Lambda Layer to normalize both my input and output data in the range 0-1? Or i don't need to use the MinMaxScale at all for that purpose (like theres an easy way to do that using a Lambda Layer)?

2 - How can i do the inverse transformation of the output variables later? I've read someting about `scaler.inverse_transform()`, but not really sure where should i put it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should do this outside of the model.

Comment: I don't recommend this if you want something robust, but a hacky solution is to just stick a batchnorm layer directly onto the input.

Comment: Allright, i've done it inside my python generator. After generating the input and output data, i used the MinMaxScale to normalize them.

Comment: Please share your solution....